# Use pumping lemma to prove grammar is not context free?

Tags: context-free-grammar, formal-languages, pumping-lemma

I'm trying to prove that `L={y#x|(y is a substring of x)  ∧x,y∈{a,b}^* }` is not context free using the pumping lemma, but I can't seem to do that. If

```
|vy|≠ε ,|vxy|≤k , uv^n xy^n z∈L ,∀n≥0
```

Then either `vxy` has both `a` and `b`, or only `b` or only `a`.

How can I pump it in order to show that?

Comment: Isn't the pumping lemma only useful for showing a language *isn't* context free?  ie: Even if it satisfies the conditions, it might still not be?

Comment: This is off topic for SO.  It belongs on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @andand No, it does not; [cstheory.SE] is only for *research level* TCS. This belongs to [cs.SE] which has in fact a good [reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/265/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-context-free) on the matter.

Answer (score -2):

I agree with cHao, use the pumping lemma to show that a language isn't Context Free. To prove that a language is context free build a Context Free grammar or a DFA.

`{y#x | y` is a subset of `x`} over the alphabet `{a, b}*` does not appear to be context free just with a quick look.

Let `s = (a|b)^p#(a|b)^(2p)` so this is the string where `p` characters precede the `#` and `2p` after to make this an easy subset.

We now need to decompose this string into `x y^i z` parts where `|y| > 0` and `|xy| = p`. So the `y` must be made of any string of characters before the `#`. We can "pump up" this string now s.t. the first string before the `#` is larger than the second. This is no longer a subset of the second half. This is a contradiction so this language is not context free.

Comment: The pumping lemma you use is for regular languages. The pumping lemma for context-free languages would involve a decomposition into `uvxyz`, where both `v` and `y` would be pumped. As presented, the form of the above proof would be applicable to other non-regular, context free languages, "proving" them to be non-context-free. Try it with `a^nb^n`, taking `s=a^pb^p`. Also, `|xy| ≤ p` in the regular version, and `vxy ≤ p` in the context-free version.